# Lumen: Using Models without Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Is it possible to have Eloquent disabled in lumen bootstrap file and still use Lumen (Eloquent) Models?

Comment: Well, yes, but they would become ordinary classes. But yes, you can instanciate them!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried it a month ago and I received some exception, but right now I see it works!

Comment: @El_Matella what do you mean by `they would become ordinary classes`? What features I don't have if I don't enable Eloquent?

Comment: I think that the Eloquent methods won't work, like `User::find(4)`

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Thanks to @El_Matella for his correct answer. It's impossible to use Lumen Models without having Eloquent enabled.

**Description of problem I faced**: I was unable to use lumen models while having eloquent disabled. I added a custom validator in AppServiceProvider boot method and boom! Lumen models works! What happens is that ValidationServiceProvider enables eloquent:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationServiceProvider.php#L57

```
$this->app->singleton('validation.presence', function ($app) {
    return new DatabasePresenceVerifier($app['db']);
});
```

$app['db'] causes following function calls:

> ./vendor/illuminate/validation/ValidationServiceProvider.php(57): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('db')
>
> ./vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(1182): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('db')

Which Application->make('db') is equal to $app->withEloquent()!